# If $f^{-1}(x)$ is continuous, is $f(x)$ also continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, inverse

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a one-to-one function with $f(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$. If $f^{-1}(x)$ is continuous $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, prove or disprove that $f(x)$ is continuous $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you prove that such a function $f$ must be strictly monotone?

Comment: If $f$ is a bijection, then so is $f^{-1}$. Are bijections (on $\mathbb{R}$) continuous?

Comment: @MiloBrandt I don't think I can do so. Any hint?

Comment: @Jason What is the definition of continuity?

Comment: @EugenCovaci A function f is continuous $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $$\lim_\limits{x\to x_0}{f(x)}=f(x_0)$$ for all $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think it a duplicate, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368824/is-the-inverse-of-a-continuous-bijective-function-also-continuous?rq=1

Comment: When you figured out what Milo Brandt suggested and don't know where to go from there, I suggest you have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/714121/12885).

Comment: @MiloBrandt I found out that by using the IVT many times with a<c<b by reductio ad absurdum we end up with $f^{-1}$ being strictly monotone, so f is also strictly monotone.